# Pythonv3.6.0 execution in XAMPP

Tags: python, apache, xampp

I am using XAMPP for Windows 5.5.30 for executing python programs,in which I have recieved error.
I had made changes in httpd.conf page ,

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp .py
ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict
```

and

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
                   default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
                   home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm index.py
</IfModule>
```

The simple Python code which I executed for testing :

```
#!C:\Users\PRABHU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python

print ("Content-type: text/html\n")
print ("<html><head><title>Hello World from Python</title></head><body>Hello World from a Python CGI Script</body></html>")
```

This was the error I recieved  :

> Server error!
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request.
>
> Error message:  couldn't create child process: 720002: hello.py
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 500
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.5.30

and for this code without `#!C:\Users\PRABHU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python`

```
print ("Content-type: text/html\n")
print ("<html><head><title>Hello World from Python</title></head><body>Hello World from a Python CGI Script</body></html>")
```

I am recieving error :

> Server error!
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in
>   a CGI script.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 500
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.5.30

help me in executing simple python program in XAMPP .

Answer (score 0):

```
#!C:\Users\PRABHU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python
```

Change this line to

```
#!C:\Users\PRABHU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python\python.exe
```

So finally it will look like this

```
#!C:\Users\PRABHU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
print("Content-type: text/html\n")
print("<html><head><title>Hello World from Python</title></head><body>Hello World from a Python CGI Script</body></html>")
```

it worked for me